# I cannot see/open html visualisation in this project

Tags: python, html, github, web-scraping, visualization

I try to run FollowerFactory code from github: ([https://github.com/elaineo/FollowerFactory)

It is a python code for extracting followers on Twitter and then visualising them. Python file works fine. I get the output in form of a csv file. But the index.html file does nothing. I do not get any visualisation. Why could that be? I don´t get any errors. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you read the [**Troubleshooting**](https://github.com/elaineo/FollowerFactory#troubleshooting) section in the Github page

Comment: yes. I have already fixed the problem. Thanks!